# Get the property name of type T in instance of IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Person Class:

```
public class Person {

public long Id { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
public string FaxNo { get; set; }
public int Age { get; set; }
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

}
```

And People Instance like this:

```
IEnumerable<Person> people = new List<Person>() { /* Define people */ }
```

So I need to Get the Property Names of Person Use People, of course I can use this:

```
string fr = people.FirstOrDefault().FirstName;
```

So what about the situation that the `people` have not any instance of `Person`?
I know when we have not any `Person` so we have not any `FirstName` But I need to access it in List View of ASP.NET MVC I want Use like this:

```
  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
```

Does any one have any idea about it?

Answer (score 3):

If `people` is empty, then `FirstOrDefault()` will return null, so you'll get a null reference exception.

It's not clear what you *want* to happen here, but if you just want `null` you could use:

```
string fr = people.Select(p => p.FirstName).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will do the projection *first* - so `FirstOrDefault()` will just return `null` if there are no people, or the first name of the first person otherwise.

Comment: Ok, in edit or create or detail views of MVC we use  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName) for show the properties name also in this approach we can display the DisplayName attribute as a Name of property but in List View we have an IEnumerable of type so we can't use this approach and I am interesting to use Display or DisplayName attributes in List Views.

Comment: @Saeid: Sorry, it's really not clear to me what you're trying to do, or what this has to do with an empty collection...

Comment: As I said I just want to change the Display of properties name in List View of MVC and maybe(not always) the collection passed to the view was empty. but thanks for answer

Comment: @Saeid: But where does the `FirstOrDefault()` call come in? It's not clear *where* you're trying to put the code. You've said how you want to use `DisplayFor`, but not what happens when you just try that... I'd expect that if you're displaying a *collection*, it shouldn't display any values at all if the collection is empty...

Comment: I mentioned to `FirstOrDefault()` to say that I know I can use it when the collection is not empty, also you are right about: it shouldn't display any values at all if the collection is empty, but I don't need any values, I just want some names that set it in Attributes like `Display` attribute, and this name not any relevant to values if values set or is null.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer but I hope can Help, you can define an empty `Person` instance and use that like the following:

```
@model IEnumerable<YourNameSpace.Models.Person>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
YourNameSpace.Models.Person p = new YourNameSpace.Models.Person();
}
```

And :

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => p.FirstName)
```